# gulp.lastrun returns a value only after the done() function is called

Tags: gulp

Recently I have started using Gulp 4. In my gulpfile I have a simple task:

```
gulp.task('example',
    gulp.series(function(done) {
        console.log(gulp.lastRun('example'));
        done();
        console.log(gulp.lastRun('example'));
    })
);
```

It should print the timestamp marking the task's last execution twice. It does, but every time I run the task the timestamp is defined only after the `done()` function is called. The output is similar to:

```
[12:00:25] Using gulpfile c:\xampp\htdocs\gulp\gulpfile.js
[12:00:25] Starting 'example'...
[12:00:25] Starting '<anonymous>'...
undefined
[12:00:25] Finished '<anonymous>' after 2.14 ms
[12:00:25] Finished 'example' after 4.39 ms
1482058825484
```

So the first time I am trying to get the `lastRun` timestamp it is undefined and the second time it returns a timestamp for the current run (because `done()` has already been called). How to get the actual last run timestamp?

Edited:

I created this example task only to determine how `lastRun` works. A "real-life" task would be something like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts',
    gulp.series(function scriptsInternal() {
        return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js', {since: gulp.lastRun('scripts')})
            .pipe(cached('ugly'))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(remember('ugly'))
            .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
        })
);
```

In this case `lastRun('scripts')` also returns `undefined`. At least I suppose so, because the task takes 2 seconds to complete wether I use the `since` option or not. [Here](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-incremental-builds/#the-gulp-4-way) is another sample task that should work, but does it?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. If you read the docs you'll see that `lastRun()` doesn't return the last run of a task, but the last **successful** run. A run isn't successful unless `done()` has been called. Your only option is to record the timestamp yourself in the first line of your task and not rely on `lastRun()`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've edited my question. I still don't get how I'm supposed to use `lastRun` to deal only with files modified since the previous task execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question yet again.

The `lastRun()` call does not work as I expected it to because it will return a correct timestamp only as long as gulp is running. When you execute a task manually using:

```
>gulp [task name]
```

command, gulp starts but soon terminates (on task completion). This way the `lastRun` timestamp is not "remembered". Every time you run a task, another gulp process starts.

For `lastRun` to work properly you need a watcher. The watcher will run in the background and trigger the `example` task whenever a file from a glob is changed. Because the watcher does not stop on task completion, gulp will remember the last run timestamp.